# Clears Tags in Set-AzureRmTag using Automation Account

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm tying to change a value on a tag, using an automation script. The users will have a startup script, which will change the shutdown tag key from true to false.

When I set the tags individually using the script below it sets the tag value to false. The current setting is true.

When I use the automation script it wipes all the tags, however If I specify the vm in the script the automaton account works and changes the key value from false to true.

I can't see what I'm missing. This is from a webhook and is running as a powershell script, not a workflow.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [object]$WebhookData            
    )

    Write-Output "------------------------------------------------"
    Write-Output "`nConnecting to Azure Automation"

    $Connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
    Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Connection.TenantID `
    -ApplicationId $Connection.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Connection.CertificateThumbprint

    $RunbookVersion = "0.0.17"
    $timeStartUTC     = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

    Write-Output "Workflow started: Runbook Version is $RunbookVersion"
    Write-Output "System time is: $(Get-Date)"

    Write-Output "`nGetting tagged resources"
    Write-Output "------------------------------------------------"

    $ResourceGroupFilter  = ""

    $SupportedEnvironments = "DEV, Test, PREProd, Prod"

    $isWebhookDataNull = $WebhookData -eq $null
    Write-Output "Is webhook data null ? :  $($isWebhookDataNull)"

      # If runbook was called from Webhook, WebhookData will not be null.
    If ($WebhookData -ne $null) {
        # Collect properties of WebhookData
        $WebhookName     =     $WebhookData.WebhookName
        $WebhookHeaders  =     $WebhookData.RequestHeader
        $WebhookBody     =     $WebhookData.RequestBody

        $body = $WebhookBody | ConvertFrom-Json

        $UserEmail = $body.user.email
        Write-Output "Runbook started from webhook '$WebhookName' by '$($body.user.email)' for environment '$($body.environment)'"
        Write-Output "Message body: " $WebhookBody

    }
    else {
        Write-Error "Runbook mean to be started only from webhook."
    }

    If ($body.environment.ToUpper() -eq 'DEV') {       
        $ResourceGroupFilter = 'The-DEV-RG'
    }
    if ($ResourceGroupFilter -eq "") {
     Exit 1
    }
    if($VMRG -eq ''){
        Write-Output "No resource groups matched for selected environment. Webhook cant progress further, exiting.."
        Write-Error "No resource groups matched for selected environment. Webhook cant progress further, exiting.."
        Exit 1
    }   
            $rgs = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$rg*"} 
        foreach ($rg in $rgs) 
        {
        $vms = Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName
            $vms.ForEach({
                $tags = $_.Tags
                $tags['ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop'] = "$False";
                Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $_.Id -Tag $tags -Force -Verbose
        })
        }
    ForEach ($vm in $vms) {
        Start-AzureRmVM -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Verbose
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i dont see anything wrong with the tagging part. take a look [here](https://paste.ee/p/DZHTJ) did minor improvements. also this doesnt change from false to true, quite the contrary

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks for getting back to me earlier, I’ve been playing around with it and what I’ve realised is that the script is fine, it only happens when I run it using an automation account with runas permissions. Not sure how to amend the permissions, but thanks for your help. Also thanks for the heads up on the second segment (start-AzureRmVm) I need to check that bit.

Comment: @NorrinRad I add an answer to your question. Hope it will help more people.

Comment: @NorrinRad I give a feedback to Azure about this. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/33263911-using-latest-azure-power-shell-on-automation-runbo

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT thanks for your help, i thought I did accept your script as the answer. Sorry must’ve made a mistake, anyway accepted your answer, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root reason is your local Azure Power Shell is latest version, but in Azure automation account, it is not latest version.  I test in my lab, older version does not support this.

You need upgrade Azure Power Shell version. More information about this please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673782/hashtable-not-being-read-as-hashtable-in-azure-automation).