# Hashtable not being read as hashtable in Azure Automation

Tags: powershell, azure

We have a piece of code which works perfectly in Powershell ISE, however when we use the same code in Azure automation, it clears the tags.

```
    $rgs = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$rg*"} 
foreach ($rg in $rgs) 
{
$vms = Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName
    $vms.ForEach({
        $tags = $vm.Tags
        $tags['ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop'] = "$False";
        Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $_.Id -Tag $tags -Force -Verbose
})
}
```

What I've managed to establish so far is that the code `Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $_.Id -Tag $tags -Force -Verbose` does not see $tags as a hastable. I've done some debugging and I can see `$tags = $vm.Tags` is a hashtable.

I looked around on google and I've seen a few mentions of using `[system.collections.hashtable]` to specify it is a hashtable, but this is where my powershell is limited. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I've tried doing`ResourceId $_.Id -Tag [system.collections.hashtable]$tags` but that didn't work.

What we are trying to do is change a tag value from true to false. The Key is Shutdown_AllowStop and the value is currently set to True.

Thanks in advance (and really hoping this makes sense) :)

Comment: The [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ce5ed10-262f-49eb-9c5c-36670f65d39b/error-with-hashtables-in-azure-powershell-runbooks?forum=azureautomation) maybe helpful.

Comment: I test in my lab, the `tags` data type is `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]`, you need convert it to hashtable.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT Thanks for checking, how would I convert it to hash table, I have tried (as TheMadTachbician suggested) using ‘[hashtable]$tags=$_.tags’ or is there another way I have missed.

Comment: I try this `$hash = [System.Collections.Hashtable]::new($tag)`. I test in my lab, data type is right. But I also could not add tags.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT Thanks Shui.. I’ll check that when I get into work, just curious did it work in your lab environment?

Comment: Yes, your code works on my local PC. But it does not work on runbook.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT thanks.  My original code works on my local machine using ISE, could I ask what is the engine background engine on automation Runbook, think understanding the difference between that and powershell ISE engine will help resolve this. If that makes sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164732/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-norrin-rad).

Comment: If possible, could you use [hybrid workers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker).

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT hi we did consider runbooks through hybrid workers but we felt the best option to manage resources in azure was azure automation. Would we need to change much, sorry not worked with hybrid workers

Comment: OK, I know. You could check my latest code. But it still does not work, I will still update this.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT hi sorry got dragged into meetings this morning, so im a bit stuck here, looks like it can’t be done, I just don’t see why a single value cannot be changed using automation, any ideas please 

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT hi Shui could you check the chat please.

Comment: Hi, I find the reason, after I upgrade Power Shell in automation account. All issue solved. I send e-mail about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script works for me.

```
$rgs = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like *$rg*"} 

foreach ($rg in $rgs) 
{
$vms = Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName
    foreach ($vm in $vms)
    {
        $tags = $vm.Tags
        foreach ($tag in $tags)
        {

            $tag['ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop'] = "$True";
            Write-Output ("Showing VM's resource ID " + $vm.ID)
            Write-output ("Show VM's tag "+[System.Collections.Hashtable]::new($tag))
            $hash = [System.Collections.Hashtable]::new($tag)
            $hash['ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop']
            Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $vm.ID -Tag $hash  -ApiVersion "2017-12-01" -Force -Verbose
        }

    }
}
```

But you need update Azure Power Shell version in Automation Account, if you don't do this, the script does not work.

[image]

This is my test result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the issue. It works in the ISE because you defined `$vm` somewhere earlier in the session. Change it to `$tags = $_.Tags` and this should work for you.

**Edit:** So I took a look and the `Get-AzureRmVm` cmdlet returns an object where the `Tags` property is a horrid type when what they want in return is a hashtable. What it returns is:

```
[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]]
```

Or Dictionary`2 for short if you run a .GetType() on it. What you can do to get around this is to explicitly declare your type when you define it:

```
[hashtable]$tags = $_.Tags
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly :)   Sorry rookie mistake, I added that as I thought it was not reading the tags, with that it comes back as having a null array.. sorry the code is actually `$tags = $_.Tags`

Comment: Ok, looked into it a little more and updated my answer. Hopefully that resolves this.

Comment: Hi Thanks for that, I've hd a play around and still nothing, I used the exact code from ISE and it set the value t "Maybe" and then used the script with your amendments `[hashtable]$tags = $_.Tags` and still nothing. It's had me dumbfounded for days..

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason that you aren't using `Update-AzureRmVm`?

Comment: Hi, I have tried using `$vm | Update-AzureRmVm -Tags $Tags` but same result.. :(